# External path between two different shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm going straight to the point.

I have two different circles, with two different radii and centers, like shown below:

[image]

How can i obtain a complex figure like this one instead?

[image]

Here's the code which generates the two circles:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (c1) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (c2) at (-1.3,0);

        \draw [ultra thick] (c1) circle (1.5);
        \draw [ultra thick] (c2) circle (0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this simply case where you final path only consists of arc segments, you can draw this diagram

1. by finding the intersections of those two circles with the `intersections` library
2. and then drawing the arcs to those points either

   1. by calculating the needed start and end angles for `arc[…]` (e.g. with `let … in`) or
   2. by using `arcto` which does this calculation for you. This needs the `ext.paths.arcto` library of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext).

Here I'm choosing `ext.paths.arcto`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  intersections,  
  ext.paths.arcto,% https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (c1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (c2) at (-1.3,0);

\path[name path=C1] (c1) circle [radius=1.5];
\path[name path=C2] (c2) circle [radius=0.5];
\draw[ultra thick, name intersections={of=C1 and C2}]
      ([shift=(0:1.5)]c1) arcto[radius=1.5] (intersection-1)
                          arcto[radius=0.5] (intersection-2)
                          arcto[radius=1.5] cycle;
%\draw [red,thick] (c1) circle [radius=1.5];
%\draw [red,thick] (c2) circle [radius=0.5];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `spath3` library can do this (if it doesn't work with the version with your tex distribution, try the one from [`github`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3)).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/660906/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (c1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (c2) at (-1.3,0);

\path[spath/save=large circle] circle[radius=1.5];
\path[spath/save=small circle] (c2) circle[radius=0.5];

\tikzset{
  spath/remove empty components=large circle,
  spath/remove empty components=small circle,
  spath/split at intersections={large circle}{small circle},
  spath/get components of={large circle}\largeCpts,
  spath/get components of={small circle}\smallCpts,
}

\draw[
  ultra thick,
  spath/use={\getComponentOf\largeCpts{2}},
  spath/use={\getComponentOf\smallCpts{1},weld},
  spath/adjust and close=current,
];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: outer edge of two overlapping circles]

(There's something a bit odd with the final junction - it isn't joining the end back to the beginning.  I need to investigate that further.)

*Added in edit:* I've figured out the issue - the coordinates at the join are not *quite* the same.  Fortunately, I'd already put in place a fix for that: the key `adjust and close`.  I've changed the code but haven't updated the screenshot.