TikZ -- defining a path from theintersection of two circles
Is it possible to define a path in TikZ following along two intersecting circles, one piece on each of them?
I can do it by computing the intersection and the angles as in:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{1.5};
        \path[draw, line width=0.8pt]
        (1-\r^2/2,{\r*sqrt(4-\r^2)/2}) arc ({acos(1-\r^2/2)}:{360-acos(1-\r^2/2)}:1)
        arc ({180 + asin(sqrt(4-\r^2)/2)}:{540 - asin(sqrt(4-\r^2)/2)}:\r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


producing

but I would like to be able to define the path from the intersection of the two curves without having to go through the computation.

Yup, the spath3 TikZ library can do that.

(if you don't actually need a path, you could first draw two black circles and then overlay them with 2 smaller white circles.)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You mean "smaller with disks" or "smaller pieces of circles" with the same radius? How would you go about finding out where the pieces start and stop without calculating the point?

@TeXApprentice smaller radius \begin{tikzpicture} \fill (0,0) circle (1) (1,0) circle (1.5); \fill[white] (0,0) circle (0.95) (1,0) circle (1.45); \end{tikzpicture}

@TeXApprentice Or same radius \begin{tikzpicture} \filldraw[line width=1.6pt] (0,0) circle (1) (1,0) circle (1.5); \fill[white] (0,0) circle (1) (1,0) circle (1.5); \end{tikzpicture}

(one might even be able to automate this with postactions)

This is even the same diagram as in Q660906.

Very nice find!

@TeXApprentice this would appear to be a duplicate of the question that Qrrbrbirlbel links to. Do you agree? If so, we'll close this as a duplicate.

Yes, this shoud be closed as a duplicate.

@Qrrbrbirlbel This is definitely a duplicate, but I am having problems following your solution on https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/660906. Moving the center of the small circle seems to lead to failure executing the code.
